# How to fix ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined in jest test of Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, jsdom

I have a unit test that is checking to see if a particular item is rendered on the page.  This unit test fails and I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

       6 | import { unformatPhoneNumber } from '../../../utils/formatter';
       7 | import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
    >  8 | import DOMPurify from 'isomorphic-dompurify';
```

Based on the other stackoverflow questions on this subject, I added a jest.config.js file and a jest.setup.js file in the root of my project.
This is what I have in my jest.config.js, which I copied from the Next.js example repo here,
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest-babel

```
// You can learn more about each option below in the Jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.

module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!**/*.d.ts', '!**/node_modules/**'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',

    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`,

    // Handle module aliases
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',

    '^@/pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};
```

This is what I have in the jest.setup.js,

```
// Optional: configure or set up a testing framework before each test.
// If you delete this file, remove `setupFilesAfterEnv` from `jest.config.js`

// Used for __tests__/testing-library.js
// Learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util';
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

After adding this, I am still getting the same error.  I am using node v16.18.0.

This is a Nextjs, Typescript, React app.  I also have a jest-config.d.ts file with the following in it:

```
declare const root: any;
export { root as rootDir };
export declare const setupFilesAfterEnv: string['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'];
export declare const testMatch: string[];
export declare const testPathIgnorePatterns: string[];
export declare const coveragePathIgnorePatterns: string[];
export declare const coverageDirectory: string;
//# sourceMappingURL=jest-config.d.ts.map
```

I don't know if I need to add anything into this file.

Comment: The problem seems to be `import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util'`. Do you have an installed `'util'` module? What is `'util'`? Because it clearly is not something that contains a `TextEncoder` export, according to `jest`.

Comment: Also note *"looking for an answer from a reputable source"* is likely preventing people from answering your question. In general, it means *"an answer coming from official documentation or from the individual(s) involved in developing (or at least maintaining) the technology in question"*. In your case, it would mean an answer from developers/maintainers of `jest`, I suppose. It's unlikely they would read the question. You have better chances of reaching them by opening an issue on `jest`'s repo.